# Is there some way to automatically "follow"/pre-determine the release date for stable/GA PostgreSQL 14?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

I currently have PostgreSQL 12.x installed. I'm putting off my Windows re-installation for the PostgreSQL 14 release, because I want to skip the entire generation 13 for superstitious reasons. Yes, you heard that right. I'm seriously so scared of running a "13" version that I've gone out of my way to avoid it, waiting forever for PG 14. Since it will require a scary dump/restore, I also want to avoid doing that twice in "short" succession.

> A Note on the PostgreSQL 14 Beta
>
> This release marks the third beta release of PostgreSQL 14 and puts the community one step closer to general availability tentatively around the end of the third quarter.

Source: https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/postgresql-134-128-1113-1018-9623-and-14-beta-3-released-2277/

I also found this: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/release-14.html

> Release date: 2021-??-?? (AS OF 2021-06-20)

Is that likely to be updated regularly? Or will it simply be set once it actually *is* released?

I'm trying to be able to auto-fetch a target date so that I can auto-put the PG 14 release in my calendar and "countdown" so that I can look forward to it.

The "around the end of the third quarter" claim sounds like it's due soon, but if it's not even in "RC" mode yet, that doesn't sound too promising to me.

PS: No matter how solid and problem-free 13.x is claimed to be, I still cannot shake the feeling that it will corrupt all my data permanently.

Comment: PostgreSQL 14 has been released.

Answer (score 5):

If you follow the [gitlog](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=shortlog;h=refs/heads/REL_14_STABLE), 14.0 should "stamped" on a Monday to be released (barring catastrophe) on that Thursday.

That "stamping" is also when the anticipated release date (T+3) is injected into the release notes.

Answer (score 3):

The Release Management Team announces the release date when this date will be known. Such announce will be made in *pgsql-hackers* mailing list. [Timeline for PostgreSQL 13 was](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/0fe40569-9a27-3511-f8ac-cdd2768dc8ff%40postgresql.org):

- announce on 2020-09-02
- 2020-09-17 RC1
- 2020-09-24 generally available

I believe the announcement for PostgreSQL 14 will be in a next few weeks. But there is no automatic subscription to this announcement only.

---

> Since it will require a scary dump/restore

Why? `pg_upgrade` can skip releases, for example upgrade from 9.6 to 14.

> No matter how solid and problem-free 13.x is claimed to be, I still cannot shake the feeling that it will corrupt all my data permanently.

Any `(x).0` release may contain serious bugs. So you may prefer in your calendar something like February 10th, 2022 or May 12th, 2022 (the dates of next [minor updates](https://www.postgresql.org/developer/roadmap/)).

Comment: I don't recall any .0 release from Postgres that wasn't production ready. Yes, software can always contain bugs and it can always contain serious bugs. But Postgres has a very good track record regarding their quality and the chances for serious bugs in a .0 release is not really higher than for any other release.

Comment: Um... No idea what you mean about "pg_upgrade", but a complete dump/restore is required for every update to a new major version according to the manual.

Comment: @user16508174 , *"A dump/restore using pg_dumpall or use of pg_upgrade or logical replication is required for those wishing to migrate data from any previous release."* - usual sentence in notes for a major release. `pg_upgrade` is typically used for production databases to reduce downtime.

Comment: Yet again, PG confuses me with duplicate choices/tools where one is far superior but I've never heard of until many years of using the bad one...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, as a postgresql contributor, I agree and would say, "Start using the new version, it has awesome features". As a DBA I want to add "except for production systems, wait a little". In postgresql, new features will only appear in the next release. There could be bugs in new feature itself, in some refactoring for such features. It cannot be part of a minor release. So x.0 naturally has higher chances for bugs. Actually we lack of testers and reviewers for new patches (and many cool things takes years because of that). Committers are humans too and cannot check everything.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  I would only use a .0 release in a serious production system if it had new features that were really important to me.  The threat of nasty bugs is not extremely high but high enough to make is not worthwhile when the benefit is also not high.  Bragging rights is not enough--I can wait for the .2 release.  I will certainly be *testing* on .0, though.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, PostgreSQL v14 will be released as soon as no serious problems manifest with the release candidate. There is no exact date, but it will be end of September or beginning of October, as usual.

Out of curiosity: what are you going to do if v14 is released on 2021-10-13?

Answer (score 1):

Postgres tends to have very few release candidates, so one or two more betas and one RC and then the final release may well be what happens.

You can extrapolate the release date from the [release history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL#Release_history). If past years are anything to go by, look for the final version late September, early October.

You can also check the [RSS Feed](https://www.postgresql.org/news/pgsql.rss) from the [News Archive](https://www.postgresql.org/about/newsarchive/pgsql/) as a-horse-with-no-name suggested.

Personally I wouldn't upgrade as soon as 14.0 is released but wait several months. We tend to upgrade early the year after a major release.